# pySpark not found: value % %pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am using spark cluster on EMR with Zepplin notebook along with it

I opened the Zepplin notebook in webbroswer and created a notebook, typed in

```
%pyspark
```

get the error

```
<console>:26: error: not found: value % %pyspark
```

how can I use pyspark in Zepplin ? What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Is $SPARK_HOME/python in sys.path of python you are running?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking into your zeppelin.python property. Maybe your default system python and Zeppelins' Python have a conflict in their versions.

Try adding this line to your .bashrc

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/$USER/path/to/your/default/system/python
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed settig SPARK_HOME but if it isnt the case you can use findspark library 
https://github.com/minrk/findspark/blob/master/README.md

Import findspark
findspark.find(path to spark folder)

Or if you intend to use pyspark 2.2 you can directly do 
pip install pyspark

And if the above line throws error try it with sudo

Answer (score 0):

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

Answer (score 0):

Set these environment variables in IDE or system variables

```
SPARK_HOME = <path to spark home>

PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS = "--master local[2] pyspark-shell"

PYTHONPATH = %SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\build;%PYTHONPATH%;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the interpreter binding for spark is not set up in that note. There is a gear icon on the right next to a lock and keyboard icon.

Click that icon and the interpreters list will be displayed. Make sure the spark binding is **blue**.

If the spark binding is not listed, use some of these other answers to understand why Zeppelin does not have an available spark binding.